# How can config bond interface down after slave interfaces has been down

Tags: networking, rhel, network-interface, bonding

I'm using Redhat 7. I tried to use bond interface but I've run into a problem. After all slave interfaces are down, bond interface is still up.

Example:

I have bond0 and 2 slaves for bond0: eth0, eth1.  I run `ifdown eth0`, `ifdown eth1`, I want bond0 to be down after these slave interfaces are down.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use either of the following:

```
$ ifconfig down bond0
```

-or-

```
$ ip link set bond0 down
```